# form_tag with date_select in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I pass the selected date to a date_select in a form_tag

I would like something like

```
date_select_tag(object_name, value, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

Is that possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at select_date:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_date

It has the form:

```
select_date(date = Date.current, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

Comment: That works except that now all fields have name=date[day] ... So i'm not sure how to use params do differentiate between start_date and end_date for example.

Comment: :name is probably something you can pass in as a params to either options or html_options... go have a look at the link I put above to figure out how to do that :)

Comment: yes you can set it but it doesn't work. Exmaple: select_date Date.today - 5.days, {}, {:name => "something"}. I get <select id="date_year" name="something">...<select id="date_day" name="something">... It doesn't append the usual i1..i5 at the end of the name.

Comment: looks like :prefix may be your friend. Here's more info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html

google is your friend :)

Comment: Hadn't seen the common attributes section at the top of the page :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can with a date_select_tag according to the doc.

If this form is not linked to a model, what you could do is create an object yourself with the needed methods. You could then use form_for and the date_select method:

```
form_for my_object do |f|
    f.date_select :date
end
```

If there is `date` method on your object, I think it should work.

ps: take a look at these helpers though, might be easier ;)

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select